# Azure SignalR Service | Asp.Net Web Api | Console client

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, signalr-hub

I am able to connect to Azure SignalR Service from Asp.Net Web Application using its Access-Key. Asp.Net Web App creates and hosts a hub over Azure SignalR Service. I created a c# console client and connected to Asp.Net Web Application's SignalR Hub using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` library.

Questions:

1. Should I always implement a middleware like Asp.Net Web Application and rely on it to create and talk over Hub?
   Yes, based on Samara & other sources, we have a couple of choices.

   - Consume REST API from console app to host a hub (*Azure SignalR*) as a server and serve the clients\ subscribers as portal. This supports uni-directional messaging.
   - Consume REST API from Azure Functions (*make it serverless*) to host a hub (*Azure SignalR*) as a server and serve the clients\ subscribers as portal. This supports uni-directional messaging.
   - Host a hub (*Azure SignalR*) from Asp.Net managed Web API with auth() layer and cater clients via API. This supports fully blown bi-directional messaging.
2. Is it not possible to directly talk to Azure SignalR Service from c# console to create a Hub and send my messages over Hub?

   - Consume REST API from console app to host a hub (*Azure SignalR*) as a server and serve the clients\ subscribers as portal. This supports uni-directional messaging.
   - Consume REST API from Azure Functions (*make it serverless*) to host a hub (*Azure SignalR*) as a server and serve the clients\ subscribers as portal. This supports uni-directional messaging.

I am new to Azure SignalR Service; please assist me on above questions. My questions are almost answered. Hope it helps!

P.S. People does not have real answers, stay away

Comment: You can use whatever type of project you want to in order to achieve your goal. SignalR is just a system for implementing websocket connections, which is usually done in conjuction with web services, but that isn't a requirement.

Comment: So, from console client, I found a github project sample called 'Serverless'. It talks to Azure SignalR Service to create a hub, broadcast messages to individual user to all users. But individual user could not post messages to Hub. How to make it two data sync like chat applications.

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT ,Azure SignalR service integration with Asp.Net Apps and Console client seems far different to each other. Integration with SignalR is not seamless.

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT, Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question a bit better. I think you are talking about the sample code here? https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/master/samples/Serverless

If you want to make a chat application you would modify the code to combine the two functions. I was able to do this by updating the program.cs to run both code sets. It isn't a complete chat client- all messages still say they are coming from the other user, but I hope it gives you a better idea of how this works.

```
    app.Command("client", cmd =>
    {
        cmd.Description = "Start a client to listen to the service";
        cmd.HelpOption("--help");

        var userId = cmd.Argument("<userId>", "Set User ID");

        cmd.OnExecute(async () =>
        {
            var connectionString = connectionStringOption.Value() ?? configuration["Azure:SignalR:ConnectionString"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString) || !hubOption.HasValue())
            {
                MissOptions();
                return 0;
            }

            var client = new ClientHandler(connectionString, hubOption.Value(), userId.Value);

            await client.StartAsync();

//Add the server to the client so we can talk both ways
            var server = new ServerHandler(connectionString, hubOption.Value());
            await server.Start();


            Console.ReadLine();
            await client.DisposeAsync();

            return 0;
        });
    });
```

There is something to keep in mind, and why most of these examples add an API layer over the top of the SignalR service. In order to create a connection to the service, you are using a key. If you embed that into your console app and then distibute it, *anyone with the app now has the ability to control all of your hubs by extracting the key*. Unless you trust all your users with this power, then adding an API layer is the way to go- the user authenticates to the API, and the API decides what permissions they have on the hub.

Comment: SamaraSoucy-MSFT, it turns out to be, like SQL Server or other back-end servers, we are supposed to create a middle-ware to exchange messages via Azure SignalR Service Hub.

Comment: SamaraSoucy-MSFT, unless we build a chat app or portable applications, we are fine consuming Azure SignalR Service by Console App.

Comment: Yes, SamaraSoucy-MSFT. I have verified this sample yesterday. Serverless sample was uni-directional. Only server can broadcast messages to subscribers. Subscribers cannot post back the messages to Server, if needed in edge cases.

Comment: I surfed for the reasons. It looks like Azure SignalR Service REST API does not allow individual users or subscribers to post back messages to Server Hub.

Comment: I forgot to thank you for the efforts! I will try an exercise tomorrow and share the results.